# Find if the MUSIC_STREAM is active

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I would like to get a callback when the music stream starts being active. Say I start a webview with a youtube video, or I launch a music on spotify using their API. Eventually, the music stream will starts. Maybe not immediately, but I would like to receive a callback once it happens. Because I might have to deal with multiple external audio players I would like something general and not player specific.

Can I observe something or receive an intent as soon as the MUSIC_STREAM starts playing?

I would like to have something like:

```
musicActiveReceiver.setListener(Callback {warningTextView.text = "Music stream is on."})
```

This is almost great:

```
private class BecomingNoisyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY) {
            // Pause the playback
        }
    }
}
```

but do not want to use `AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY` because it assumes the problem comes from the speaker. In my case I also want to catch the case where the headset is being used.

A possibility would be to check regularly `AudioManager.isMusicActive()` but I would prefer to avoid this.

Comment: Please include some code so that we know what you're referring to

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question lacks concrete context which would make it much easier to answer it. Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly.